# How can we align action sheet label to left like in iTunes and pages

Tags: iphone, swift3, ios8, xcode8, leftalign

[image: iTunes Image]

I am able to align image to right but not able to set the label of action sheet to left. I have used paragraph style and tried to align it but it doesn't act like a normal button and not able add image to it.

[image: This is what I am able to achieve]

. In UIAlertController I am NOT able to access label through subviews. Can anyone suggest any way to achieve this.

Comment: KiranMayee Maddi may i know how you done that your images towards right? what the snippet code you used to achieve that?

Comment: I have customized the action sheet by adding a table view to it. This helped me to add other functionalities too.

Comment: You mean.. You used tableview in place of actionsheet.. to achieve mentioned UI.. correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: I used the alert controller and added table view as a subview for that.

Comment: How did you manage to put the image on the right side of the UIAlertAction? setValueForKey "image" puts it to the left, as far as I know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use this.

```
let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add to a Playlist", style: .default, handler: nil)
action.setValue((Your Alignment), forKey: "_titleTextAlignment")
action.setValue((Your Image), forKey: "_image")
```